# activation/configuration of ttys0 - ttys3

Tags: wine, serial-port, ham-radio

I am an amateur radio operator and love digital radio communications. I need to get my com ports functional (ttys0, s1, s2 and s3).

I have been searching for a way to activate/configure these ports.

I have downloaded cute com and serial port terminal Gtk term and added dialup to my group as well as root. I have been on this site looking for the correct method to get things going.

I intend to use fldigi (with rig control) and mini com for packet operations. If I can get wine to work, Ham Radio Deluxe, Multipsk among others will be forthcoming. From Windows the port settings were 8,N,1 at 9600 no hardware or software control.

I would prefer to not use the terminal but as long as I get things going that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do anything like this before, but does this video help?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=kBRsWTdngRc

It's old, but seems to cover some configuration of "minicom" etc before loading cutecom. Maybe that is what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever add root to your groups. Adding dialout (not dialup) and  tty to your group  should be enough. To setup wine with serial interfaces, you have to make a symbolic link in ".wine/dosdevices" linking  to the tty device and name it "com1" for example.